# el bar / la barra

Tags: pronombres

De *Mi mundo adorado* por Sonia Sotomayor:

> En esencia, era *un bar* para estudiantes graduados en el que se
>   vendían los tragos más baratos de New Haven. Como vicepresidenta de
>   operacíones, él me contrató para trabajar en la puerta, recibiendo los
>   boletos y comprobando las identificaciones.Yo hubiese preferido
>   trabajar en *la barra*, que pagaba mejor, pero era muy buena en el
>   área de seguridad.

Why is the *bar* first referred to in the masculine and then later in the feminine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"El bar" is the business, the place from the door to the toilets.

"La barra" is the desk where the waiter works.

The first one is a copy from the english "bar" with the meaning of "pub". The second one is the translation of the english "bar" with the meaning of, well, a bar inside a pub.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that

`el bar` refers to the actual building, the establishment,

while `la barra` refers to the actual bar, the big wooden table the customers hover over while they drink and order more drinks.